# How can I find all points of a given triangle for a refined triangulation in matplotlib?

Tags: python, matplotlib, triangulation, finite-element-analysis

To give you some background information (If this doesen't interest you at all you may skip the whole next paragraph):

I am working on my thesis on building a 2D-FEM solver for the poisson equation from "scratch". The basic idea is to divide an area into triangles (the "Finite Elements") and to rewrite the PDE to some kind of integral equation, which basically reduces the problem to some numerical integration over these triangles and consequently a (huge) system of linear equations (Ax=b).

For the coding I am using python/numpy/matplotlib. I tried to obtain a triangulation by using `matplotlib.tri`. This works fine but here comes the problem:

To plot the solution I need to evaluate some functions (lets call them phi) on each each triangle. Therefore I thought about using `matplitlib.tri.UniformTriRefiner.refine_triangulation` to divide the each triangle into several subtriangles. Now I would like to call phi on every node of each subtriangle, but I need to know the original triangle I am currently working on (to determine the right phi). `refine_triangulation` has, according to the documentation[1], one optional return value `found_index`, which should contain the points of the original triangle (before subdividing).

Unfortunately if you search this array for all subnodes given some index you only get some of the subnodes contained by the original triangle because most nodes belong to several triangles and they are only added to one of these.

The picture shows the original triangulation (black) and the subtriangles (red). The black dots show all nodes returned for triangle `113`, in this case 3 out of 6 are missing (I added the code at the end).

[image: mesh]

Does anyone know a way to obtain *all* the nodes of each subtriangle for a given triangle or a better approach to plot this?

Thanks! :)

---

[1] http://matplotlib.org/dev/api/tri_api.html

Code dump:

```
#!/usr/local/bin/python3

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri


x =np.array([-1.1288,-0.27786,0.80753,1.0593,-0.1563,-0.62518,-0.95861,-0.78842,-0.61823,-0.44805,-0.096961,0.083936,0.26483,0.44573,0.62663,0.85789,0.90825,0.95861,1.009,0.85673,0.65412,0.45152,0.24891,0.04631,-0.27352,-0.39074,-0.50796,-0.79305,-0.96093,0.093606,-0.70378,0.72463,-0.27503,0.64406,-0.30976,0.40348,0.28319,-0.10986,-0.073193,0.87604,-0.88885,0.19124,-0.00036351,-0.51538,-0.3409,0.68238,0.43689,-0.6176,0.54328,-0.079635,0.31319,0.73076,-0.79277,0.87668,-0.20567,-0.21595,0.11589,0.26013,0.32212,0.54986,0.45791,0.12746,-0.44664,-0.28559,0.11883,0.061646,-0.50891,-0.48716,-0.62684,0.57669,0.74722,0.81603,0.37258,0.22964,-0.41324,-0.1382,-0.37681,-0.035599,0.037716,-0.068816,-0.22796,-0.060578,-0.43952,-0.20434])
y =np.array([0.11288,0.68162,0.23444,-0.60781,-0.75543,-0.29088,0.22663,0.34038,0.45412,0.56787,0.60709,0.53256,0.45803,0.3835,0.30897,0.065991,-0.10246,-0.27091,-0.43936,-0.63242,-0.65702,-0.68162,-0.70622,-0.73082,-0.63929,-0.52315,-0.40702,-0.1563,-0.021708,-0.11758,0.14118,-0.37025,0.45932,0.091961,0.11512,-0.16654,0.13428,-0.36803,0.3966,-0.48949,0.13423,-0.40068,0.1352,0.31481,-0.20473,-0.21478,0.01804,-0.055294,-0.48544,-0.56999,0.29215,-0.52686,0.0078785,-0.36062,0.26627,-0.065918,0.28055,-0.050238,-0.53119,-0.28196,0.20482,-0.56317,0.41544,-0.35988,0.061395,-0.29014,0.14657,-0.18565,0.27854,-0.10593,-0.083011,-0.23355,-0.34932,-0.22943,-0.043161,0.11161,0.2849,-0.010632,-0.43886,-0.18259,-0.49244,0.23716,-0.32913,-0.23735])

t1 =np.array([7,28,8,9,11,10,2,12,14,16,15,3,17,18,20,19,4,21,22,34,25,23,5,26,13,29,31,33,47,41,44,40,24,68,48,27,58,8,66,50,49,11,54,60,55,39,55,49,46,1,48,40,64,58,51,57,56,56,64,16,47,57,47,67,6,60,73,66,59,12,51,20,32,31,28,32,71,65,63,76,68,76,37,78,36,59,22,32,66,37,14,62,23,9,35,80,50,37,30,36,38,64,31,67,45,67,31,34,36,70,34,32,17,42,49,30,42,35,48,39,35,33,44,30,43,50,42,38,30,25,38,43,55,26,45,45,38])
t2 =np.array([1,6,7,8,2,9,10,11,13,3,14,15,16,17,4,18,19,20,21,15,5,22,24,25,12,28,8,10,34,29,9,19,23,6,6,26,30,31,30,24,32,33,18,36,35,33,33,21,32,29,31,32,38,37,13,39,35,45,26,34,37,43,36,35,27,46,36,38,42,39,37,40,49,41,48,40,46,43,44,56,45,43,51,56,47,49,49,46,42,47,51,42,59,44,55,56,38,57,58,58,50,45,48,48,56,44,67,47,60,46,70,54,71,59,60,66,73,67,68,55,56,63,67,65,76,62,66,66,78,50,64,57,76,64,68,64,80])
t3 =np.array([41,48,41,69,33,63,33,39,51,34,61,34,71,72,40,54,40,52,49,61,50,59,50,81,57,53,41,63,61,53,69,54,62,83,68,83,74,69,80,62,60,39,72,73,76,55,77,52,72,41,53,52,84,65,57,82,75,84,81,71,58,65,70,77,83,70,74,79,62,57,61,52,52,53,53,54,72,78,77,78,75,82,57,80,58,73,59,60,74,61,61,79,62,63,77,84,81,65,65,74,79,83,67,75,75,69,69,70,70,71,71,72,72,73,73,74,74,75,75,82,76,77,77,78,78,79,79,80,80,81,81,82,82,83,83,84,84])

tri = np.vstack((t1-1,t2-1,t3-1)).transpose()

my_tri = mtri.Triangulation(x,y, tri)

refiner = mtri.UniformTriRefiner(my_tri)

my_tri2, index = refiner.refine_triangulation(subdiv=1, return_tri_index=True)

#plot the original triangulation
for t in my_tri.triangles:
    t_i = [t[0], t[1], t[2], t[0]]
    plt.plot(x[t_i],y[t_i] ,'k',linewidth=1.5)

#plot the refined triangulation
for t in my_tri2.triangles:
    t_i = [t[0], t[1], t[2], t[0]]
    plt.plot(my_tri2.x[t_i],my_tri2.y[t_i] ,'r',linewidth=0.5)

#mark all points corresponding to index 113 in the original triangulation
for i in range(0,my_tri2.x.size):
    if index[i] == 113:
        plt.plot(my_tri2.x[i],my_tri2.y[i] ,'ok')

plt.show()
```

Comment: I'm not familiar with matplot lib, but if it cant give you the connectivity info you need i would be simple  to just do your own mesh refinement so you could keep track.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume your phi function is not guaranteed to be continuous between adjacent triangles, otherwise you could simply eveluate phi in the triangle returned by `matplotlib.tri.UniformTriRefiner.refine_triangulation` (which is a valid containing triangle).

Then one easy solution is to delete the connectivity information *before* refining the triangulation, which will duplicate nodes shared by 2 triangles - or more. (This will also allow you to contour-plot your discontinuous phi field over the triangulation, in case you need it.)
[image]

Here below your code modified with a `delete_connectivity` function.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.tri as mtri

def delete_connectivity(triangulation):
    x, y = triangulation.x, triangulation.y
    triangles = triangulation.triangles
    (ntri, _) = triangles.shape
    new_x = x[triangles].ravel()
    new_y = y[triangles].ravel()
    new_triangles = np.arange(ntri * 3, dtype=np.int32).reshape(ntri, 3)
    return mtri.Triangulation(new_x, new_y, new_triangles)


x =np.array([-1.1288,-0.27786,0.80753,1.0593,-0.1563,-0.62518,-0.95861,-0.78842,-0.61823,-0.44805,-0.096961,0.083936,0.26483,0.44573,0.62663,0.85789,0.90825,0.95861,1.009,0.85673,0.65412,0.45152,0.24891,0.04631,-0.27352,-0.39074,-0.50796,-0.79305,-0.96093,0.093606,-0.70378,0.72463,-0.27503,0.64406,-0.30976,0.40348,0.28319,-0.10986,-0.073193,0.87604,-0.88885,0.19124,-0.00036351,-0.51538,-0.3409,0.68238,0.43689,-0.6176,0.54328,-0.079635,0.31319,0.73076,-0.79277,0.87668,-0.20567,-0.21595,0.11589,0.26013,0.32212,0.54986,0.45791,0.12746,-0.44664,-0.28559,0.11883,0.061646,-0.50891,-0.48716,-0.62684,0.57669,0.74722,0.81603,0.37258,0.22964,-0.41324,-0.1382,-0.37681,-0.035599,0.037716,-0.068816,-0.22796,-0.060578,-0.43952,-0.20434])
y =np.array([0.11288,0.68162,0.23444,-0.60781,-0.75543,-0.29088,0.22663,0.34038,0.45412,0.56787,0.60709,0.53256,0.45803,0.3835,0.30897,0.065991,-0.10246,-0.27091,-0.43936,-0.63242,-0.65702,-0.68162,-0.70622,-0.73082,-0.63929,-0.52315,-0.40702,-0.1563,-0.021708,-0.11758,0.14118,-0.37025,0.45932,0.091961,0.11512,-0.16654,0.13428,-0.36803,0.3966,-0.48949,0.13423,-0.40068,0.1352,0.31481,-0.20473,-0.21478,0.01804,-0.055294,-0.48544,-0.56999,0.29215,-0.52686,0.0078785,-0.36062,0.26627,-0.065918,0.28055,-0.050238,-0.53119,-0.28196,0.20482,-0.56317,0.41544,-0.35988,0.061395,-0.29014,0.14657,-0.18565,0.27854,-0.10593,-0.083011,-0.23355,-0.34932,-0.22943,-0.043161,0.11161,0.2849,-0.010632,-0.43886,-0.18259,-0.49244,0.23716,-0.32913,-0.23735])

t1 =np.array([7,28,8,9,11,10,2,12,14,16,15,3,17,18,20,19,4,21,22,34,25,23,5,26,13,29,31,33,47,41,44,40,24,68,48,27,58,8,66,50,49,11,54,60,55,39,55,49,46,1,48,40,64,58,51,57,56,56,64,16,47,57,47,67,6,60,73,66,59,12,51,20,32,31,28,32,71,65,63,76,68,76,37,78,36,59,22,32,66,37,14,62,23,9,35,80,50,37,30,36,38,64,31,67,45,67,31,34,36,70,34,32,17,42,49,30,42,35,48,39,35,33,44,30,43,50,42,38,30,25,38,43,55,26,45,45,38])
t2 =np.array([1,6,7,8,2,9,10,11,13,3,14,15,16,17,4,18,19,20,21,15,5,22,24,25,12,28,8,10,34,29,9,19,23,6,6,26,30,31,30,24,32,33,18,36,35,33,33,21,32,29,31,32,38,37,13,39,35,45,26,34,37,43,36,35,27,46,36,38,42,39,37,40,49,41,48,40,46,43,44,56,45,43,51,56,47,49,49,46,42,47,51,42,59,44,55,56,38,57,58,58,50,45,48,48,56,44,67,47,60,46,70,54,71,59,60,66,73,67,68,55,56,63,67,65,76,62,66,66,78,50,64,57,76,64,68,64,80])
t3 =np.array([41,48,41,69,33,63,33,39,51,34,61,34,71,72,40,54,40,52,49,61,50,59,50,81,57,53,41,63,61,53,69,54,62,83,68,83,74,69,80,62,60,39,72,73,76,55,77,52,72,41,53,52,84,65,57,82,75,84,81,71,58,65,70,77,83,70,74,79,62,57,61,52,52,53,53,54,72,78,77,78,75,82,57,80,58,73,59,60,74,61,61,79,62,63,77,84,81,65,65,74,79,83,67,75,75,69,69,70,70,71,71,72,72,73,73,74,74,75,75,82,76,77,77,78,78,79,79,80,80,81,81,82,82,83,83,84,84])

tri = np.vstack((t1-1,t2-1,t3-1)).transpose()

my_tri = mtri.Triangulation(x,y, tri)
my_tri = delete_connectivity(my_tri)


refiner = mtri.UniformTriRefiner(my_tri)

my_tri2, index = refiner.refine_triangulation(subdiv=1, return_tri_index=True)

#plot the original triangulation
plt.triplot(my_tri,color='red', linewidth=1.5)

#plot the refined triangulation
plt.triplot(my_tri2, color='red', linewidth=0.5)

#mark all points corresponding to index 113 in the original triangulation
for i in range(0, my_tri2.x.size):
    if index[i] == 113:
        plt.plot(my_tri2.x[i],my_tri2.y[i] ,'ok')

plt.show()
```

PS:

Also note that, in case you need to adapt `matplotlib.tri.UniformTriRefiner.refine_triangulation` to your particular case, it is pure python :
https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/master/lib/matplotlib/tri/trirefine.py